# How to use environment variables for serverless in GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, github-actions, serverless-framework

I was trying to deploy serverless framework on AWS using GitHub Actions where I was previously using Jenkins.

Here is my workflow:

```yaml
name: Deploy to Dev
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  Deploy-to-dev:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: 
      - name: Get code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install NodeJs
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          npm install
          npm install -g serverless
      - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v3
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_NON_PROD }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_NON_PROD }}
          aws-region: us-east-1
      - name: Deploy to Serverless
        run: Environment=dev serverless deploy --stage dev
```

This is failing with error:

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "functions.xyz.environment.id": Value not found at "self" source,
  - Cannot resolve variable at "functions.xyz.environment.id": Value not found at "self" source
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`
```

This was running fine from Jenkins:

```bash
Environment=$env_name serverless deploy --stage $env_name
```

I was passing `$env_name` from Jenkins parameter as `dev`.

Comment: This works properly with jenkins FYI

Comment: In GitHub use Actions secrets and variables to store Environment variable.

Comment: you mean get the dev in Environment=$env_name serverless deploy --stage $env_name from secrets like access keys? @Zeeshan it ws not working even when i hard code it

Comment: Check https://github.com/serverless/github-action. Observe the env vars configured for AWS in the usage.

Comment: maybe I was not on point in my question. I don't wanna use the env variable. I  know how to do that. The issue is even when i pass it it is not taking. Weather we hard code it or pass from env varibles. The Environment=dev is not working @Azeem

Comment: Here the Environment is a keyword of sever less framework which i use in my severless.yml like ${env:Environment} I tried changing the name Environment to envv doesn't work

Comment: @Nitink: Can you try using https://github.com/serverless/github-action? See if that works. Compare the `serverless` version being installed during your workflow now with the one in that action i.e. `3.x`.

Comment: We are not allowed to use that action as it is not verfied

Comment: Well, if it works in Jenkins then it should work in your GHA workflow too with the same configuration. You can try setting env var with the `env` context or with `export` command under `run` section.

Comment: run: Environment=dev serverless deploy --stage dev i changed this to run: npx Environment=dev serverless deploy --stage dev now its getting npm ERR! Invalid tag name "Environment=dev" of package "Environment=dev": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
- name: Deploy to Serverless
  run: |
     export Environment=dev 
     serverless deploy --stage dev
```